# Is there a way to have a VBA script that runs every time an Excel file opens?

Tags: vba, excel

What I'm looking for is having the auto_open() function run on every excel file that is created. Is there a way that this can be implemented?

Comment: Are you asking if there's a way to automatically program the auto_open() into every excel workbook that you create? Or are you asking if there's a way to get `Sub auto_open()` to run every time you open one document?

Comment: The question is to get auto_open() with some code to run in every excel file created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Type `?Application.StartupPath` in the immediate window to find your `XLSTART` folder.
2. Inside this folder, there will be a template file named `Book.xlt` or something similar.
3. Open that file and put your `Auto_Open()` event inside that template, then save it as a template in the `XLSTART` Folder. Be sure it actually saves in the correct place and overwrites the original template.   NOTE: You may have to change the template file type to `.xltm` and delete the original `.xlt` version since it will have macros in it.
4. Your `Auto_Open()` event should now be in every new file you create.

[Automatically open a workbook template or worksheet template when you start Excel](https://support.office.com/en-sg/article/Customize-how-Excel-starts-6509b9af-2cc8-4fb6-9ef5-cf5f1d292c19)

Comment: On a related note, if you want to have some code be available in every new `Sheet` that gets added, you can do that by changing the `Sheet.xlt` template instead. I'm sure somebody could think of a reason to use that.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a separate workbook that contains the code you want to run - for example, your Personal Macro workbook. In the Thisworkbook module of that workbook, add this:

```
Private WithEvents appExcel As Excel.Application
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
   Set appExcel = Application
End Sub

Private Sub appExcel_WorkbookOpen(ByVal Wb As Workbook)
    Call Macro1
End Sub
```

where Macro1 is the code you want to run for each workbook.